# Issue encoding/decoding file to/from S3 (Realm, Swift)

Tags: swift, mongodb, amazon-s3, swiftui, realm

I am working on a SwiftUI app on iOS using Realm (Sync) as back-end. I have been following the article on o-fish ([Realm Data and Partitioning Strategy Behind the WildAid O-FISH Mobile Apps | MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/products/realm/realm-data-architecture-ofish-app)) to enable users to attach pictures while offline.

My Photo model:

```
class Photo: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable {

@Persisted(primaryKey: true ) var _id: ObjectId

@Persisted var picture: Data?

@Persisted var pictureUrl: String

convenience init (pictureUrl: String = "", picture: Data? = Data()) {

self .init()

self .pictureUrl = pictureUrl

self .picture = picture

}
```

For testing purpose, in my iOS app code, I am writing in the realm like the following:

```
.onChange(of: image) { _ in
                if(image != nil) {
                    if let newData = image!.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5) {
                        try! realm.write {
                            realm.add(Photo(picture: newData))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Which as explained in the article, will trigger functions on App Services to (1) upload to S3 and (2) replace the field ID by S3’s generated link.

I created my AWS S3 bucket and managed to upload some blob on it through the upload function.

```
exports = async function(imageName, file) {
  
  const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

  AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId : <key>
    secretAccessKey : <key>,
    region: <region>
  });
  
  const s3 = new AWS.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01'})
  const bucketName = <bucket name>

  return s3.upload({
        "Bucket": bucketName,
        "Key" : imageName,
        "Body": file.toBase64(),
        "ACL": "public-read",
        "ContentType": "image/jpeg",
        }).promise()
}
```

Regarding my issue: from what I understand, the file saved on S3 is in base64 format. Thus it is impossible to download the file from S3 and open it in an image viewer, is that correct? Furthermore, I am now trying to display the base64 image on the iOS app but I only get decoding errors… :

```
let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: URL) // URL is the new S3 image link

If let image = UIImage(data: Data(base64Encoded: data.base64EncodedString())!) {
...
}
```

Doing a curl on the image link gives a long string looking like

> /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAASABIAAD/4QBYRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgAAgESAAMAAAABAAEAAIdpAAQAAAABAAAAJgAAAAAAA6ABAAMAAAABAAEAAKACAAQAAAABAAAGhKADAAQAAAABAAAJxAAAAAD/wAARCAnEBoQDASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/…

Is there something I am missing either in the S3 upload or in the Swift/SwiftUI decoding?

Comment: could you add: `print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))`, just after
 `let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: URL)`.
 Do you get the same string as with curl? If so, try:
 `if let str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8),
 let imageData = Data(base64Encoded: str) {
  let img = UIImage(data: imageData) ?? UIImage()
}`

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine thank you so much for your reply!! Looks like the output Xcode console prints actually the content during execution then it gets replaced by blank spaces afterwards. 
In one line with the dirty force-unwrap: ``UIImage(data: Data(base64Encoded: String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)!) ``
Don't hesitate to post your comment so that I can mark it as an answer. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this example code, where you turn the `data` you receive into a `String`, then base64 decode it, for use into a `UIImage`:

```
if let str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8), let imageData = Data(base64Encoded: str) {   
   let img = UIImage(data: imageData) ?? UIImage() 
}
```